# Many-to-many and hierarchical database design

Tags: mysql, django, database, many-to-many, relational-database

i'm designing a database and run into some problems:

I have a `Document` entity consisting of many fields. Mostly i want to use the same version of that document but sometimes users should be able to customize some of the fields for a specific usage of the document. Not customized fields should use the value of the parent document as a default. Changes to the parent document should get propagated to any not customized field of a specific usage.

I have a table `Document`:

```
Document:
id | field1| field2 | field3|  parentDocumentId
```

For parent documents is `parentDocumentId = Null`. Customized usages of a document have the new value for the customized fields saved and for not customized fields simply `null`.

1. Is this a good design?
2. Furthermore the `Document` entity has a many-To-many relationship with another entity `Course`. My problem now is when i look at a row of `Document` with `parentDocumentId != null` and `courses = null` i can't determine if the relationship is either not customized by the user yet and i should use the value of the parent document or the field is customized by the user and simply has no `courses`. How can i solve that?

Thanks

Comment: When you deal with versioned documents it is best to use a NoSQL database, as most of the structure already are versioned and contain the timestamp of the change ... If you **have to** use a RDBS (Relational DB). Your question implies that you want to understand `latest` changed for your documents and to answer if has no courses, that would be a `left join where courses.id=null` (probably ... as you don't provide the full structure of both tables and their indexes).

Comment: 1. 'Good' is subjective, but this is an edge list, which is a reasonable model for storing hierarchical data

Comment: 2. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query